# Define colour transparency in relation to existing colour

Tags: color, context, transparency

## Background

Using ConTeXt to develop a nice theme where users can change the colour scheme, but still get the same "feeling" for the output, primary, secondary, and tertiary colours are defined. For example:

```
\definecolor[ColourSecondary][h=9A957A]
```

Each colour can then be "lightened" by setting its transparency:

```
\definecolor[ColourSecondaryLighter][h=9A957A,a=1,t=.5]
\definecolor[ColourSecondaryLightest][h=9A957A,a=1,t=.3]
```

This works but is not ideal.

## Problem

The `ColourSecondary` value of `9A957A` is repeated for the lighter colours, resulting in triplicated code.

## Question

How do you create a transparent variation on an existing colour?

For example:

```
\definecolor[ColourSecondaryLighter][h=\tohex{ColourSecondary},a=1,t=.5]
```

The following did not work:

```
\definecolor[ColourSecondaryLighter][1.0(ColourSecondary),a=1,t=.5]
```

## References

- http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/definecolor

Comment: It is relatively easy to extend `\definecolor` so that something like `\definecolor[one][two][t=0.5, a=1]` works. Why don't you send a feature request to the mailing list?

Comment: @Aditya: Is there an issue tracker for ConTeXt? If so, I'd gladly log the issue there. I think Taco mentioned somewhere that he'd prefer them logged rather than e-mailed.

Comment: For something like this, I think that it makes more sense to post on the mailing list because (i) mailing list is more active than the issue tracker, (ii) I _think_ that this should have a quick solution (but I don't know all the internals, so I may be wrong). I think that Taco's comment might have been for LuaTeX rather than ConTeXt.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a [spot colour](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/definespotcolor) instead. Spot colours can be defined using three arguments instead of two arguments, like `\definecolor`. The first argument is the colour to define. The second argument is the colour to be use as a base. And the third argument takes the same options as `\definecolor`.

```
\definecolor     [ColourSecondary]             [h=9A957A]
\definecolor     [ColourSecondaryLighter]      [h=9A957A, a=1, t=.5]
\definecolor     [ColourSecondaryLightest]     [h=9A957A, a=1, t=.3]
\definespotcolor [ColourSecondaryLighterSpot]  [ColourSecondary]     [a=1, t=.5]
\definespotcolor [ColourSecondaryLightestSpot] [ColourSecondary]     [a=1, t=.3]

\setupblackrules [height=1cm, width=5cm]

\starttext

\blackrule[color=ColourSecondary]

%% defined using \definecolor
\dontleavehmode
\blackrule[color=ColourSecondaryLighter]
\blackrule[color=ColourSecondaryLightest]

%% defined using \definespotcolor
\dontleavehmode
\blackrule[color=ColourSecondaryLighterSpot]
\blackrule[color=ColourSecondaryLightestSpot]

\stoptext
```

[image: screenshot]