# define colors for colormap with opacity

Tags: color, transparency

Is there a way to define colors using `\definecolor` for pdflatex with `transparency` similar to [this approach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129297/define-colour-transparency-in-relation-to-existing-colour)?

Comment: color and transparency are independant settings. You can set both but there is no dedicated interface to set them together. Why do you need it?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks for your answer. Acually I was just curious, if this is possible in LaTeX, since I could not find some detailed information about it. I was planning to define the white color with no opacity for the zero value in a colormap. So the workflow then is defining the color and afterwards putting the color in the desired environment and add the opacity afterwards.